# How to get Epson Perfection V10 run on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

Tried already many different routes, installing the drivers which are now at Epson.com - installed sane libs etc., but no way to get the scanner recognized.

Anybody ran into this by chance?  Would be cool, if somebody could give me guidance here

Comment: thanks so much for your help !!... got it running the way you have described it (-:

Comment: Answer below @Braiam

Answer (score 1):

1. Install gdebi,

   `sudo apt-get install gdebi-gtk`
2. Download:

http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-s600&version=1.0.0

3. Right click the downloaded file and open with **gdebi installer**. Follow the direction and do the same to uninstall.
4. Open Simple Scan > Preferences > Source (select your scanner).

I notice there are two drivers you might want to try the latest one and if not working you can try the other one.